# Different tags for an array in XML Serialization based on the number of its elements

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xmlserializer

I want to serialize a class using `XmlSerializer`, the class is similar this

```
class X
{
    public List<Y> Childs;
    public string Name;
}
```

I would like in the output of serialization if the `Childs` List has only one member then its tag to be `Z` but if it has more that one elemnent its tag to be `L`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple solutions to this problem for example you can use :

1. [XmlAttributeOverrides](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributeoverrides(v=vs.110).aspx) as shown [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6012335/4366237).
2. [Custom Serialization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty01x675(v=vs.110).aspx) like [This](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/94061/Serialization-in-C-NET-I-Custom-Serialization).